# Error response from daemon: Container [id] is not running

Tags: docker, db2

I am using docker for first time. I created docker image for DB2 and when started to login to the instance using command,

```
sudo docker exec -i -t db2 /bin/bash
```

I got following error:

```
Error response from daemon: Container [id] is not running
```

I also tried to start the instance with:

```
sudo docker start [id]
```

It returned error message as:

```
Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint db2 ([id]): Bind for 0.0.0.0:50000 failed: port is already allocated
Error: failed to start containers: [id]
```

Can someone help on this?

Comment: We cannot help with so little details. Please add a few ones such as the Dockerfile, a print of the "docker ps -a" command, the details of your build command, etc.. Basicely, looks like you did not manage to "run" (docker run) your container.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a look to your error message, it shows that you're trying to run an entrypoint in a container [id] which uses port 50000, that is already being used.

That's why `docker start [id]` doesn't work.

This can be caused by several things (let me add some of them instead concrete which is the problem because you haven't expressed many details).

- `docker exec` should be used with container id that are already running, not images, not entrypoints. So, maybe you missed do `docker run` before `docker exec`. Try to do `docker run -it db2 /bin/bash` if db2 is your docker image.
- Other possibility is that your container started and entrypoint exited by any reason, without releasing port 50000. So, when you tried to re-launch without having released port, if container exited but wasn't removed, is not possible for other docker be started using this port. Let me recommend you to do `docker container prune` to clean exited previous containers.
- Maybe you're starting two or more containers from the same image (maybe *db2*) without doing any port mapping. If you want to run several instances of the same docker image you can do two things:

  1. Use *docker swarm*, *kubernetes* or similar to scale container (pod). It lets you use the same port 50000.
  2. Use a port mapping in `docker run` command: For example,

     - for first container, do `docker run -d -p 50001:50000 [docker-image] [entrypoint]`
     - for second container, do `docker run -d -p 50002:50000 [docker-image] [entrypoint]`
       In this way, you'll have several mappings from different ports to the same 50000 avoiding this error of port-reusing, but I'm not sure if this is what you want to do. I'm only trying to help you with the little information you provided.

I hope anyway it's helpful.

Comment: Explained well :) Thanks

Comment: In my case, the command 'docker run -it db2 /bin/bash' helped, I was able to debug the location of files copied to container, I was pointing to incorrect folder